# Como posso verificar se dentro de uma string há outras?

Tags: javascript, string

Em javascript, quero verificar se em uma string há pelo menos uma das seguintes outras strings: .com, .edu, .br, etc... se uma dessas strings existir na string principal, quero que retorne verdadeiro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `indexOf`para verificar se uma dessas palavras está localizada na string passada.

```js
let palavras = ".org, .edu, .edu";

console.log(palavras.indexOf(".org"));
```

Nesse exemplo o retorno será `0` a posição atual da palavra `.org`; caso a referência não exista o `indexOf` irá retornar `-1`

Para passar para uma função basta verificar o retorno

```js
let palavras = ".org, .edu, .edu";

function verificaOcorrencias(sequencia, palavra){
    if(sequencia.indexOf(palavra) !== -1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(verificaOcorrencias(palavras, ".org")); //true
console.log(verificaOcorrencias(palavras, "algo")); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer essa verificação pode usar o método *indexOf* da *String*

Este método é sensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas (por isso mudamos a a string e chave de pesquisa para maiúsculas), retorna -1 quando não encontra a chave a pesquisar caso contrário retorna a primeira posição em que a chave foi encontrada.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/search?q=uppercase

```js
const url = "omeusite.edu";

const chave = "edu";

if (url.toUpperCase().indexOf(chave.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
  alert("A chave foi encontrada!")
}
```